# Finding probability P(X<Y) given PDFs

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have searched around and couldn't find a question like this, or possiblity just couldnt interpert it, but essentially I am given two independent random variables, X and Y. I am asked to find P(X<Y) and provided with PDFs fX (x) = 1/n where 0 <= x <= n and fY (y) = 1/m where 0<= y <= m. I am not really sure how to go about this problem at all any help would be appreciated! (sorry for the poor equation writing, I haven't learned LaTex yet)

Comment: Integrate $f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ over $\{(x,y): x<y\}$.

Comment: so integral from x to y of 1/(m*n) with respect to any given variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the pdf of independent random variables, so finding the probability for the event requires integrating over the event's domain (where it intersects the support).

$\qquad\begin{align}\displaystyle\mathsf P(X<Y) ~&=~\int_{x<y}f_X(x)\,f_Y(y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm d y\\[2ex]&=~ \int_0^m\int_0^{\min(n, y)} \dfrac 1{mn}\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\end{align}$

Now, there are two cases to consider:  $~(m\leqslant n)~$ or $~(n\lt m)~$.

Comment: Thank you very much Graham! I cannot upvote quite yet on my account but when I am able to I'll be sure to return to upvote this answer, it was very helpful!